# What is the best way to write the query for joining on the tables whose column values are not the same?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I need help in wring a query. I am a beginner and confused which option would be the best way. 
The option i tried was to have a subquery with case conditions to convert all 0 to N and 1 to Y and join on the columns. Is there is any other alternate and smart way of writing?

I have two tables, one is a lookup table with all standard values. From the second table I have to lookup the column value in the first.

example
table1

```
col_1  col_2
Y        Yes
N         No
```

table 2

```
col_1    col_2
ABC      0
XYZ      1
```

the value 0 in table 2 is N in table 1 , similarly 1 is Y

How do I join these tables?

My final output should be

```
col1_1   col1_2
ABC      No
XYZ      Yes
```

Comment: If you are looking up standard values, what is "0" and "1"?  Which value is the standard?  I think your references are off.  What you want to do is not hard.

Comment: Based on your explanation of "the value 0 in table 2 is N in table 1 , similarly 1 is Y", your final output is incorrect. Are "0" and "1" id values in the lookup table, or equivalent to "YES" and "NO"?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't add the values `0` and `1` to your look up table?

Answer (score 1):

That should do the job.  But this is not optimal if you have a lot of rows.

```
select table2.col_1, table1.col_2
from table2 inner join table1
on table2.col_2 = case table1.col_1 when 'Y' then 1 when 'N' then 0 else -1 end;
```

Comment: what would be the best solution if i have lot of rows?

Comment: The best is to use same data in all tables.  If you cannot, a lookup table is an option.  Otherwise, I suspect SQL won't be able to use index.